# Eclipse not working on Mac, Java application is missing somehow

Tags: java, eclipse

so here is the thing, I accidentally deleted Xcode completely and honestly, I don't know if this has to do anything with my problem.
Today I tried to launch Eclipse but then I got an alert saying "failed to create the java virtual machine". I checked my applications and I found out that Java application is missing.
I did install Java again and launched Eclipse, this time eclipse worked but right away two problems occurred (see the attached photos)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJxvH.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIbo2.jpg).
Can someone PLEASE tell me what is going on and how to fix such a thing?

Comment: You picked a version of Java that is incompatible with your version of eclipse. Fix that and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Eclipse [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571569) and [upgrade](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) to the latest version of Eclipse.